# C: A pointer to an address of a pointer, clarification needed

Tags: c, pointers

Suppose:

```
  6   char arr[] = "ABC";
  7 
  8   char *ptr   = &arr;
  9   char *ptr2  = &ptr;
```

Using `ptr2`, how can i access elements of `c`?

I would have thought the following would work, but ... it does not.

**`**ptr2[1]`**

Comment: You should be getting a warning about incompatible pointer types for `char *ptr = &c;` as well as `char *ptr2 = &ptr;`. The type of `&c` is `(char*)[4]` (i.e. "pointer to an array of 4 chars"), not `char*`. And the type of `&ptr` is `char**`, not `char*`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You currently don't have a pointer-to-a-pointer.

Your code should be:

```
char c[] = "ABC";

char  *ptr  = c;     // Note no &
char **ptr2 = &ptr;  // Note **, not *.  This is now a pointer-to-pointer
```

Then to access, you want this:

```
(*ptr2)[1]
```

Comment: Any way i can use ptr2 without modifying original declaration?

Comment: @mac: The original declaration is not correct.  The type of `&ptr` is `char **`, you should not be assigning that to a `char *`.  If you had compiler warnings enabled, you should be seeing a warning message about it!

Comment: Yes, write `char *ptr2  = ptr`;

Comment: A pointer to a pointer ... isn't it the same thing as a pointer to an address of another pointer?

Comment: @mac: In your original code, the type of `ptr2` is `char *`, which is not a pointer-to-pointer.  It is *possible* to force it to contain the address of a pointer, but is not *correct*.

Comment: I think what i wanted to do in declaration is char *ptr2 = ptr. In this case, is this a pointer to a pointer?

Answer (score 0):

ptr is a pointer to an array so its type is `char (*ptr)[]` not `char *`

And ptr2 is a pointer to a pointer of pointer so its type is : `char (**ptr2)[]`.